# Render image to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page `http://www.mysite.com/image.aspx`, that I want to load and display an image instead of rendering HTML.

I have the ContentType of the page set to `image/png`, and here's my code:

```
using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap("http://www.google.com/images/img.png"))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

But I get an error saying:

> ***URI formats are not supported.***

How can I load an external image and render it to the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load a Bitmap using a URI - it has to be a local file to your computer.

If you want to load an image from off the web and then render it, you need to make a web request off to that specific resource and then render the bytes to the stream as you are doing.

AKA

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/images/img.png");
using(WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(response.GetResponseStream())
    {
         stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a compilation error saying `The best overloaded method match for System.IO.MemoryStream.MemoryStream(byte[]) has some invalid arguments` - is there another way to create a MemoryStream from a WebResponse?

Comment: The above referenced code sample may not be fully correct, since I just typed it out from memory. However, in the worst case, the stream you get back from `GetResponseStream` can write to the buffer in the MemoryStream directly by doing a `Read` call.